# Facebook Timeline Flash Embed Dimensions

Tags: facebook, video, facebook-timeline

When you embed a video to Facebook Timeline the maximum dimensions seem to be 304px x 227px. Can the height be taller than 227px?

Thanks.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not [Facebook help](https://www.facebook.com/help/).

Answer (score 0):

Nope, the height is controlled by Facebook.