# What are the max. dimensions for Facebook Timeline embedded videos?

Tags: facebook, flash, facebook-graph-api, embed, facebook-timeline

I can't find an answer to this question anywhere. Somebody else asked a similar question: ( [Facebook Timeline Flash Embed Dimensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8717536/facebook-timeline-flash-embed-dimensions) ) but it wasn't really answered satisfactorily.

I have a url that I embed on the news feed. It has these open graph tags:

```
<meta property="og:video:height" content="393" /> 
<meta property="og:video:width" content="386" />
```

When I post it on the news feed, it is sized correctly:

http://screencast.com/t/9h6P4Z5WQt

when I post it on the timeline, it is all wrong, almost half of the thumbnail and video is clipped, and there is clearly enough width available to display it properly.

http://screencast.com/t/i1zk74IY

I can't find documentation on this anywhere.

Comment: I think I've figured this out....on the timeline, there is a menu item "resize", that when clicked, loads the video in a way that is "correct". I suppose this is a workaround until Facebook figures out something better.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug on facebook about this: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/146723312105682

It's still not fixed.